# Annotating Methods in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, documentation, xml-documentation

I have a piece of code that needs some serious documenting and wanted to ask whether a feature similar to C#/.NET's In-code XML-Documentation is available for Embarcadero Delphi.
My aim is to display some sort of information on how to use a specific method correctly in the manner that it'd be highlighted in the Autocompletion in Delphi XE3.

Something like this (C#):

```
/// <summary>
/// Some useful information helping other developers use this method correctly
/// </summary>
public static void ADocumentedMethod();
```

Does Delphi XE3 support something like this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Which distribution of Delphi XE3 do you have ? Could you include this information into your question, please ?

Comment: @TLama shouldn't really matter, AFAIK the /// XML-doc is available since D2010, all SKUs, althought it seems to be bit buggy...

Comment: @ain, I'm talking about [`Documentation Insight`](http://edn.embarcadero.com/cs/article/41911) where, as far as I remember, were quite big restrictions in cheaper distributions of Delphi, weren't they ?

Comment: It works in Delphi 2009, too.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The feature is named *XML Documentation Comments* and is [documented here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML_Documentation_Comments). It appears to have been modelled closely on the equivalent .net feature so you should be right at home with it.

The documentation contains this example:

```
/// <summary> Removes the specified item from the collection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Item">The item to remove
/// </param>
/// <param name="Collection">The group containing the item
/// </param>
/// <remarks>
/// If parameter "Item" is null, an exception is raised.
/// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/>
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>True if the specified item is successfully removed;
/// otherwise False is returned.
/// </returns>
function RemoveItem(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
  // Non-XML DOC comment
  // ...
end;
```

which results in this help insight hint:

[image]

And there are various other ways to process and consume the documentation.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! I feel a bit stupid for not having found this though Googling.

Comment: Also this XML documentation should be present in  `interface` section of an unit in order to be displayed in external units.

Comment: Note, you can also use <exception cref="EExceptionTypeName"> for Exceptions. Problem is, the exception name (cref) is not shown in the insight hint. (10.3 Rio).

Comment: Adding to Paul's comment, the link in context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995827/delphi-helpinsight-with-summary-in-implementation So, its similar to a line of procedure or function that gets repeated in the interface, implementation.