# Delphi HelpInsight with summary in implementation

Tags: delphi

I am looking for a solution/help about Help Insight with summary tags. 
I am using Delphi Tokyo 10.2 Update 2.

1.) HelpInsight works and the function does have additional information

```
interface

type
TMyClass= class(TForm)
   private
/// <summary> Removes the specified item from the collection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Item">The item to remove
/// </param>
/// <param name="Collection">The group containing the item
/// </param>
/// <remarks>
/// If parameter "Item" is null, an exception is raised.
/// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/>
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>True if the specified item is successfully removed;
/// otherwise False is returned.
/// </returns>
       function TClass.TestFunction(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
  end;
```

2.)  HelpInsight does not add additional information

```
implementation
/// <summary> Removes the specified item from the collection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Item">The item to remove
/// </param>
/// <param name="Collection">The group containing the item
/// </param>
/// <remarks>
/// If parameter "Item" is null, an exception is raised.
/// <see cref="EArgumentNilException"/>
/// </remarks>
/// <returns>True if the specified item is successfully removed;
/// otherwise False is returned.
/// </returns>
function TClass.TestFunction(Item: Pointer; Collection: Pointer): Boolean;
begin
 // Non-XML DOC comment
  // ...
end;
```

I do not like to have summary XML Code in the interface. Is there any solution to get HelpInsight to take summary from implementation section?

Comment: Can't you use [code folding](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Code_Folding) to automatically hide the XML help comments?

Comment: Obviously i can, but still from my side of view is still code structure with summary at the top of function better.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clearly stated in the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Help_Insight), but there's one very little hint (bold text) that it does NOT work in the implemenation section:

> View > Help Insight <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
>   Displays a hint containing information about the symbol, such as type, file, **location of declaration**, and any XML documentation associated with the symbol (if available).